# nuxt-link not working within unordered list

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm trying to link up the pages to my navigation, but for some reason the `nuxt-link` component isn't working. I have it working elsewhere in the navigation, but not this specific place. Any help would be appreciated.

It is working here:
[image: working nuxt-link]

But it isn't working here:
[image: not working nuxt-link]

I blocked out classes and information that may be sensitive to my employer.

If more information is required, please let me know.

Comment: Can you please define "not working"? I'm not sure what is the issue you are facing. :(

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't working, came here to make an edit. When I said "not working", I was clicking the link and nothing was happening. I realised it's because I had a document-wide event handler for when you click outside of the dropdown and it hides the dropdown. Once I removed that handler, the link now works as expected, but now I've got another problem of finding a new way to implement the dropdown hiding when I click outside of it.